# How to get the value of each cell of tablecolumn in javafx and store in variable

Tags: mysql, javafx

I am not getting the value of each table cell of tablecolumn in variable.
How do I get value of each cell of tableview?

I tried to get cell value using this code, but it is not working and I am getting an error.

```
    int mappingid = Integer.parseInt(ocolFileOutputMappingId.getText());
    int srno = Integer.parseInt(ocolFileSrno.getText());
    String filedname = ocolFieldName.getText();
```

My full code is :

```
 @FXML
    private TableColumn<InputMappingFieldModel, Integer> ocolFileSrno;// for srno

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<InputMappingFieldModel, Integer> ocolFileOutputMappingId;//thisfor output mapping id
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<InputMappingFieldModel, String> ocolFieldName;


    upaction.setOnAction(evt -> {
    int index = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedInde);
    // swap items
    otableview.getItems().add(index - 1, otableview.getItems().remove(index));
    // select item at new position
    otableview.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index - 1);

    // code to insert shuffle data in table
    try {
    int txtmapoutputid = Integer.parseInt(outputIdText.getText());
    String sql = "update OUTPUT_MAPPING set SERIAL_NUMBER=?,FIELD_NAME=?,OUTPUT_MAPPING_ID=? where OUTPUT_ID="+txtmapoutputid;
    // System.out.println("SQL IS mapping Update "+txtmapinputid);
    PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    int mappingid = Integer.parseInt(ocolFileOutputMappingId.getText());
    int srno = Integer.parseInt(ocolFileSrno.getText());
    String filedname = ocolFieldName.getText();
    psmt.setInt(1, srno);
    psmt.setString(2, filedname);
    psmt.setInt(3, mappingid);

    psmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    otableview.getColumns().setAll(ocolFileSrno, ocolFieldName, col_spaceswap, ocolFileOutputMappingId);//remove actionColUpdate from parameter list 
    otableview.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    otableview.setItems(modelViewField);
    otableview.refresh();
    });
```

Can anyone kindly provide me the logic for how to get cell value of table column in tableview?

Comment: Is there any reason you only want the values from the visible rows?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you don't get the values from the cells, you get the values from the table's item list:

```
int index = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
InputMappingFieldModel item = otableview.getItems().get(index);

// or just
// InputMappingFieldModel item = otableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

// this assumes you are using mappingId as the property for ocolFileOutputMappingId:
int mappingId = item.getMappingId();

// and assuming you are using serNo as the property for ocolFieldName
int serNo = item.getSerNo();

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will give a try and get back to you.